# jQgrid - Is the complete product free for personal use?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am a bit confused about the license. Can anyone tell me if I can use all of the jqgrid complete with the latest updates for my personal use? I would like to use it but I am afraid that after I start they might change things and start to charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid is dual licensed under GPL and MIT licenses. This means that you get a choice of how you wish to use the license. It is possible (though not likely) that jqGrid would change their licensing scheme in the future, but, as the current version is released under the GPL/MIT dual license, someone could easily fork it and continue its development.

Basically, I don't think you have to worry too much about changes in the future. It seems that jqGrid will be supported for some time. (Which, is great. It's an excellent and well-done library.)

Comment: It was free back in year 2011. But now Tony Tomov had changed the license to make it not free anymore as of December 2014, so hence the forked jqGrid source code by OlegKi.

Answer (score 3):

jqGrid fork created by Oleg is free. Original jqGrid not not free anymore. Tony removed MIT licensing.

Answer (score -1):

According to [their website](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=154), it's free:

> The jqGrid is released under GPL and
>   MIT licenses. This license policy
>   makes the software available to
>   everyone for free (as in free beer)
>   and you can use it for commercial or
>   open source projects, without any
>   restriction (the freedom above).

Comment: FYI - web link is broken.    It was free back in year 2011.  But now Tony Tomov had changed the license to make it not free anymore as of December 2014, so hence the forked jqGrid source code by OlegKi.